# SVN merging issue

Tags: svn, merge, svn-merge

I have a issue. I am trying to merge a branch back to trunk.The branch has never been merged to trunk.The branch has been renamed couple of times. Now when i merge it stops at a specific revision number (the revision number where the branch was renamed). And when i have a look at a specific file at the revision number it shows all the old data (but the current state of the file has all the recent data). and in turns say its in conflicted state.

Is the above issue due to the fact that we have renamed that branch couple of times or because of the fact we haven't merged it from the day we created it or something else. How can i overcome this issue.

Thanks

Comment: yelling in ALL CAPS is inappropriate -- filter the title through `tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]`.

Comment: Answers to my question would be highly appericiated

Comment: What do you mean by "stops at a specific revision number"? What messages do you get from svn? In response to what specific command? Renaming an entire branch should never prevent a merge from working.

Comment: thanks ben for clearing about renaming ... the problem is say a file named A has been changed at revision 1001 and then again it has changed at 2001 so svn first checks 1001 and reports a conflicts again it reports a conflict at 2001... Is this issues because the branch is never merged to trunk ??